# How to convert an array as follows?

Tags: php

I have an array

```
[
    [
        'title' => 'title0',
        'data' => 'data0'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title1',
        'data' => 'data1'
    ]
]
```

I need to get the output

```
[
    'title' => ['title0','title1'],
    'data' => ['data0', 'data1']
]
```

Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Could you add what you already tried to your question? You could try to initialize an empty array with the appropriate keys and loop over your existing array to add the elements you want to the newly created array.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show any attempt, but I'm bored.  Just loop the keys from the first sub-array and extract that column.  No need to know what the keys are:

```
foreach(array_keys(reset($array)) as $key) {
    $result[$key] = array_column($array, $key);
}
```

You could also do it this way:

```
foreach(reset($array) as $key => $val) {
    $result[$key] = array_column($array, $key);
}
```

Or if it's as simple as those two known keys:

```
$result = ['title' => array_column($array, 'title'), 
           'data'  => array_column($array, 'data')
          ];
```

Comment: This is the best way. Lesser code and efficient. It is good to use buit-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<?php
$shortedArray = [
    'title' => [],
    'data' => []
];

$mainArray = [
    [
        'title' => 'test0',
        'data' => 'data0'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'test1',
        'data' => 'data1'
    ]
];

// Loop thru it
foreach($mainArray as $row){
  $shortedArray['title'][] = $row['title'];
  $shortedArray['data'][] = $row['data'];
}
print_r($shortedArray);
```

Hope this resolves your issue. Any query, let me know